# Airflow: Log file isn't local, Unsupported remote log location

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am not able see the logs attached to the tasks from the Airflow UI:
[image]

Log related settings in airflow.cfg file are:

- `remote_base_log_folder =`
- `base_log_folder = /home/my_projects/ksaprice_project/airflow/logs`
- `worker_log_server_port = 8793`
- `child_process_log_directory =
  /home/my_projects/ksaprice_project/airflow/logs/scheduler`

Although I am setting remote_base_log_folter it is trying to fetch the log from `http://:8793/log/tutorial/print_date/2017-08-02T00:00:00` - I don't understand this behavior. According to the settings the workers should store the logs at `/home/my_projects/ksaprice_project/airflow/logs` and they should be fetched from the same location instead of remote.

**Update**
task_instance table content:
[image]

Comment: what mode are you running the airflow in - Local, Celery? Try checking out the following URL as there is an elaborate discussion on the topic there https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/issues/44

Comment: using CeleryExecutor

Comment: could you check in the DB configured - table - task_instance . This table has column named 'hostname' from where the log URL is built and sourced. Ideally this value is same as what you get on running 'hostname' command on your worker node.

Comment: hostname column is empty string: ''

Comment: i see most of your task instances are in queued state hence having hostname empty is reasonable. Did the only 'success' task instance give you the desired output? Can you try running some basic operations like BashOperator and see if they are received by worker instance?

Comment: One more problem that facing is the scheduler is pushing in the queue defined in airflow.cfg file but the worker listening to some other queue for some reason - my tasks are not getting executed by worker. I am using rabbitmq broker. When I am checking in rabbitmq UI a queue with name:celeryev.2708e0df-7957-4e63-add9-b11beaabe6eb is getting generated automatically and the worker is listening on this queue - even if I do:`airflow worker -p celeryev.2708e0df-7957-4e63-add9-b11beaabe6eb`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150954/discussion-between-javed-and-saurabh-mishra).

Answer (score 9):

I also faced the same problem.

Setting below variables in `airflow.cfg` worked for me. Use `{hostname}` as machine's `FQDN {hostname}` instead of localhost.

```
endpoint_url = http://{hostname}:8080

base_url = http://{hostname}:8080
```

Best of luck!

Comment: the base_url is certainly important, many of the pages in the UI use it to build links dynamically. The endpoint_url appears to be used by the cli only, so I doubt it helps with this issue.

Comment: See https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/models.py#L984 for example where the log filepath is generated, and the following method log_url which uses the base_url config value.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I am not able to open the URL. Can you elaborate the fix ?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the image-1 there is a timestamp , make sure in your logs you have the folder/file with that timestamp as name ..

You are looking at UI, so first make sure you have log files created in the directory, in my case my log folder looks like

```
(AIRFLOW-ENV) [cloudera@quickstart dags]$ ll /home/cloudera/workspace/python/airflow_home/logs/my_test_dag/my_sensor_task 
total 8
-rw-rw-rw- 1 cloudera cloudera 3215 Nov 14 08:45 2017-11-12T12:00:00
-rw-rw-rw- 1 cloudera cloudera 2694 Nov 14 08:45 2017-11-14T08:36:06.920727
(AIRFLOW-ENV) [cloudera@quickstart dags]$
```

So my log URL is

```
http://localhost:8080/admin/airflow/log?task_id=my_sensor_task&dag_id=my_test_dag&execution_date=2017-11-14T08:36:06.920727
```

When you go to your DAG, and select the GRAPH-VIEW, you can see a dropdown next to "RUN", select the appropriate run, and then in the graph-view below , select the appropriate task/operator and select view-log

Comment: I think I have this problem. But I dont know why the log file with correct timestamp is not generated. Anything obvious that must be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well, and had to unpause the tasks.

```
dags_are_paused_at_creation = False
```

I also set new dags to default to unpaused in my airflow.cfg

```
dags_are_paused_at_creation = False
```