# Airflow Error - Log file isn't local

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to execute a Airflow script and get error when checking the logs of the Task_id in the Graph View:

Hi,

I am getting a log file isn't local error when running a Airflow script. given below is the error message I get from the Graph view.

[image: View of the Airflow UI - Graph View]

[image: Error log - Graph View]

I am using Sqlite DB locally and the function I am trying to execute is connecting to a Amazon Redshift DB.

Could anyone assist. Thanks..

Comment: How does your setup look like? Do you have several workers / a Celery setup or the like?

Comment: Check the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47114780/5691525

Answer (score 0):

The url looks strange: `http://:8793/log...` - the host name is missing.

It seems to me that there is no correct configuration of the `base_url` or `web_server_host` parameter in `airflow.cfg`.

If this is all setup correctly, then the settings for log storage might be off.

Comment: if I schedule these scripts they run properly. Only when I manually trigger them do I encounter this problem.

Currently these are my values in "airflow.cfg" file  web_server_host = 0.0.0.0, base_url = http://localhost:8080

Comment: yes the scheduled scripts have correct logs and performed the task as expected